# Targeting specific hours in python

Tags: python, pandas

I need a time function in python for this task :  A% = B*C  only for time between 05:00h to 00:00h, else 100%.

```
B   C    Time 
30  3    13:00
23  4    14:00 
...
43  2    22:00
...
24  3    01:00
```

I have tried this :

```
def A(B, C):
    for Time in range(00:00, 00:00)
        return B * C
    else:
        return 100%
```

But this doesn't work, and I can't use this format of time because of integers.

Comment: can you show what you've tried as this question is just asking for a solution, you should post raw data, your code to re-create the above df, any attempts, and what the desired output should be, thanks.

Comment: I've edited my quastion
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can first convert times [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then create mask by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html). Last use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print (df)
    B  C   Time
0  10  1  03:00
1  30  3  04:00
2  23  4  05:00
3  43  2  22:00
4  24  3  01:00
```

---

```
times = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time + ':00')
print (times)
0   03:00:00
1   04:00:00
2   05:00:00
3   22:00:00
4   01:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

mask = times.between('00:00:00','05:00:00')
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Time, dtype: bool

df['D'] = np.where(mask, 100, df.B * df.C)
print (df)
    B  C   Time    D
0  10  1  03:00  100
1  30  3  04:00  100
2  23  4  05:00  100
3  43  2  22:00   86
4  24  3  01:00  100
```